# Youtube caption generation

Tags: youtube-api

I am new to youtube captioning. My problem is to generate caption file (format vtt) sentence by sentence from youtube. I have tried by writing the plain text file and upload it to youtube. Youtube generates caption file correctly but its not sentence by sentence. I want to know if I want vtt file sentence by sentence then in which format I need to write my plain text file ? Following the example I have tried :

Plain text file :

`Good day, everyone, and welcome to this meeting of earnings release conference call. Today's call is being recorded. At this time for opening remarks and introductions, I would like to turn the call over to Anand Soni, Senior Director of Investor Relations. Please go ahead, sir.`

Youtube Generates like this :

```
WEBVTT

1
00:00:00.110 --> 00:00:03.759
Good day, everyone, and welcome to this meeting of 
earnings release conference

2
00:00:03.759 --> 00:00:07.860
Call. Today's call is being recorded. At this 
time for opening remarks and introductions,

3
00:00:07.860 --> 00:00:10.809
I would like to turn the call over to Anand Soni.
Senior Director of Investor Relations. Please go ahead, sir.
```

And I want like this :

```
WEBVTT

1
00:00:00.110 --> 00:00:03.759
Good day, everyone, and welcome to this meeting of 
earnings release conference Call.

2
00:00:03.759 --> 00:00:07.860
Today's call is being recorded.

3
00:00:07.860 --> 00:00:10.809
At this time for opening remarks and introductions,I would 
like to turn the call over to Anand Soni.

4
00:00:010.809 --> 00:00:11.809
Senior Director of Investor Relations. Please go ahead, sir.
```

I am doing all above things via programming language Ruby. I want to know that is there anything I need to do with my plain text file in terms of formatting so that youtube will generate the expected sentence by sentence vtt file ?

Thanks.